# CallerID Extension error 'Couldn’t communicate with a helper application'

Tags: ios, react-native, caller-id

My Application has the caller ID extension added and it is working fine in ios 14 and below.
But with iOS 15 and above following method returns Couldn’t communicate with a helper application error.

```
 [CXCallDirectoryManager.sharedInstance getEnabledStatusForExtensionWithIdentifier:EXTENSION_ID completionHandler:^(CXCallDirectoryEnabledStatus enabledStatus, NSError * _Nullable error) {

......

}
```

Check the extension and main apps bundle identifier and provision profiles but did not find any issue with configurations.